# Detect that a file has been copied to another thumb drive

Tags: file, vba, version-control, copy, version

I need to detect that a file has been copied from one thumb drive to another. The programming Language is VBA (WWB-COM) on a Win CE machine. In order to do so, I need to look at what could possibly change.

So far I have tried with these options:

- USB Disk name: another disk will have a different name, so I know it's not the original USB stick. This works fine on normal systems, but in CE 6.0 the usb drive is renamed to "Hard Disk2".
- Date file modified: this value is not changed if I copy the file from one disk to another. The only value changed is "Date file created" but this is not accessible without using FSO, which is not available on CE 6.0.

What could be something I can check through VBA that tells me that the file is not the one I am expecting?

--------ADDITIONAL INFORMATION---------

since this sticks use non-standard disk size, an option would be to retrive the size of "Hard disk2". but i was not able to find out how to do it..

here is the reference to all comands: http://www.winwrap.com/web/basic/language/?p=doc_group_overview.htm&menu=yes

Comment: Are you trying to prevent copying?